# Flutter doctor nerwork resources error about cocoapods

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://cocoapods.org/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware
installed on your computer

[image]

`Flutter install`, env have set
`PUB_HOSTED_URL https://pub.flutter-io.cn`

`FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL https://storage.flutter-io.cn`

My Operate System is Windows 11

I've tried 'flutter channel master'
which is not working at all..
How could I fix that?
But cocoapods goes error...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.